# PHP how to do unless string match..?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php unless($category['name'] == "Offer") { ?>
<p>Write this unless category name equal "Offer"</p>
<?php } ?>
```

I know it is wrong, how do you create an unless statement in PHP like there is in Rails?

Comment: `if ($category['name'] != "Offer")`?

Comment: if ($category['name'] != "Offer") ...

Comment: Do you even *know* what `unless` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if ($category['name'] != "Offer") { ?>
<p>Write this unless category name equal "Offer"</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: And with if else it would be: `<?php if ($category['name'] != "Offer") { ?>
<p>Write this unless category name equal "Offer"</p>
<?php else { ?>
<p>Write this when name equal "Offer"</p>
<?php } ?>` ?

Comment: @Railsbeginner `if($category['name'] != "Offer") { echo 'whatever1'; } else { echo 'whatever2'; }` and what you've commented is also correct, only mistake is you are not closing if bracket

Answer (score 3):

use Not Equal to `!=` operator

```
if($category['name'] != "Offer") {
   //Process here
}
```